# synchronous for loop with promises

Tags: angularjs, promise

I have the following function that works but not as I want it to since each iteration needs the results of the iteration before.

There are plenty of similar questions but I'm finding it hard to reduce the solutions down to a pattern.

How can I rewrite the following function so that each loop iteration "waits" for the one before it?

```
$scope.updateBarcode = function() {
  var itemcodes = $scope.itemcode.split(';');
  // doc is JSPDF document, fetch will add a new page to the supplied doc.
  var doc;
  //fetch will unshift the returned doc onto the supplied array.
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < itemcodes.length; i++) {
    var promise = $scope.fetch(doc, itemcodes[i],result);
    promise.then(function(){
      doc = result[0];
      if (i >= itemcodes.length) {
        doc.save(itemcodes[0] + '.pdf');
      };
    })
  };
}
```

Comment: Separate issue: Javascript does not have block scope.  `i` is not what you think it is.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to perform all the I/O in parallel?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum The library (jsPDF) I'm using doesn't currently support merging complete docs together. So each iteration needs the results of the iteration before.

Comment: @bcooper ok then, you can still fetch them in parallel and then only merge them sequentially though, can't you?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Good idea. If I rework the other functions, I won't have this issue. Thanks

Comment: @bcooper yes, you just have to `$q.all` the results and then use a simple `for` loop. That should work just fine :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the new promise from `then()` to your variable so that you build up a chain:

```
promise = promise.then(...);
```